# Button to the save draft without exiting

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It would be very useful to be able to save a draft without having to exit out of it. I prefer to be able to save often to prevent loss of work, but when I want to save, I have to close the draft and tell it to save. A button to save ,while you are editing the draft, that does not also close it would be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The draft in the app autosaves automatically, a lot. There's not a lot that a button would add.

It saves under the following circumstances:

- Every 20 seconds while the editor is visible.
- Every time you start to dismiss the editor by dragging it down, even if you change your mind and let it go back up.
- Every time you tap "Cancel" and "Save Draft".
- Every time you drag from the top of the screen to show notifications.
- Every time we get a memory warning.
- Every time you leave the app.
- Every time you preview or submit.

Comment: If I'm using the Apple Watch, can you make it save in sync with my heartbeat?

Comment: That would kill the battery.  I recommend doing meditation and mindfulness training to bring your heartbeat down to a healthy 3 beats per minute. (I am not a doctor and this is not medical advice.)

Answer (score 0):

They save automatically. Sometimes, or at least in my experience, you will be able to see some text at the bottom of the document that says "draft saved" that appears automatically without exiting.

If it *only* saved by exiting, I see no reason to save work other than when you want to exit.

Comment: When you are like me and are prone to bumping things by accident, accidentally closing apps when you are trying to switch back, and other things, you learn the lesson to save often. It probably doesn't help that I am a bit paranoid too.